# Problem calling a function than returns a query on OracleDatabase

Tags: python, oracle, plsql

I tried to call a function from other script on python, the function must return a query than executes in the database, but it gives me an error because it looks like python can use ";", I tried to eliminate every single ";" in the query, after execute the query, there's an error again "oracledb.DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"

```py
#This is the function
def queryUpdate0():
    return f"""declare 
                cursor conver_0 is  
                    SELECT a.rowid row_id,  
                    a.PERIODO,a.MSISDN,a.PROCESO,a.PROCESO_2
                    FROM DGB_Fct_Unfcd_Ocp_Hst a
                Begin
                    For c in conver_0 Loop
                        Update DGB_Fct_Unfcd_Ocp_Hst
                        set PROCESO = null,
                            PROCESO_2 = null
                        Where rowid = c.row_id
                        and PERIODO = '{currentDate}'
                    End Loop
                    Commit
                End"""


#This is how I execute the query in the other script
query6 = queries.queryUpdate0()
cursor.execute(query6)
```

(The cursor is already defined)

I already tried other queries with different statements and they gives no errors.

Comment: Hi Miguel. Are you using `cx_oracle`? You should not have removed the `;` characters - what error was it giving you before? And what is the value of `currentDate`? Is it a date or a string variable? Please also take a look at the [cx_oracle examples](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html#anonymous-pl-sql-blocks) for calling PL/SQL code like this.

Comment: It's not `cx_oracle`, it's `oracledb`, and the value of `currentDate` is a string variable. Because in the DB the datatype of that column is string.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't build queries using string concatenation (or template strings) as that is how you introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities. Use a bind variable instead.
- You do not need to use a cursor, or loops, or PL/SQL and can do it all in a single `UPDATE` query.

Like this:

```python
cursor.execute(
   """Update DGB_Fct_Unfcd_Ocp_Hst
set    PROCESO = null,
       PROCESO_2 = null
Where  PERIODO = :dt""",
   [currentDate]
)
```

If `currentDate` is always today's date then just use `SYSDATE`:

```python
cursor.execute(
   """Update DGB_Fct_Unfcd_Ocp_Hst
set    PROCESO = null,
       PROCESO_2 = null
Where  PERIODO >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    PERIODO <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1"""
)
```

If you want to fix your code then put the `;` back in (you want to only remove the statement terminator, which for PL/SQL is the trailing `/`, and not the `;`, which is the terminator for SQL statements):

```python
def queryUpdate0():
    return f"""declare
                cursor conver_0 is  
                    SELECT a.rowid row_id,  
                    a.PERIODO,a.MSISDN,a.PROCESO,a.PROCESO_2
                    FROM DGB_Fct_Unfcd_Ocp_Hst a;
                Begin
                    For c in conver_0 Loop
                        Update DGB_Fct_Unfcd_Ocp_Hst
                        set PROCESO = null,
                            PROCESO_2 = null
                        Where rowid = c.row_id
                        and PERIODO = :dt;
                    End Loop;
                    Commit;
                End;"""

query6 = queries.queryUpdate0()
cursor.execute(query6, [currentDate])
```

But it will be very inefficient.